# Hot water in shower and washer but not other faucets

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, kitchens

I have no hot water in bathroom or kitchen sinks but hot water does go in shower and washing machine. My water heater appears okay and runs. I run "hot" water faucet in sink for a minute but still only get cold water. Both bathroom sinks and kitchen went bad at the same time so it appears that it is the same issue and not independent of each other.  Any ideas as to what is going on?

Comment: I'd check the hot water valves under the sinks to see if they're fully open by turning them to the left.  Also check to see if there is a closed valve on the hot water heater itself. A closed valve handle is perpendicular to the pipe. Some water heater installations have these valves, some don't.

Comment: In addition to what @DAS suggested, also check for any kind of anti-scald hot water mixers and make sure the settings are correct and that the mixer isn't defective.

Comment: Some valves are knobs that have to be turned multiple times to open/close. Sure, the quarter turn gate valves are _better_, but they're not installed everywhere. The "multiple turn handle" valves are still lefty-loosey (open) righty-tighty (closed), though.